# Springboot- load the correct swagger definition using springfox-swagger for an api

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Missing something obvious. I have created an api in Java using springboot and springfox-swagger.

There are no problems with the api itself, works as expected. The Swagger UI works 'mostly' ok.

When I load the swagger page, it defaults to the definition : `<myapi>/v3/api-docs`

This then produces an error on load 'definition not found'

However if I manually type in 'v2' as the definition everything loads fine. (`<myapi>/v2/api-docs`)

How do I update the definition version to 'v2' so it automatically loads? Or vice versa have my definition as v3?
It doesn't break anything but is an annoyance at this point. I suspect I am missing updating a config file somewhere.